# My Hero Splendor 100cc Gives Mileage 40 - 45 Km/L

Tags: motorcycle, hero-honda

2 months ago I changed my Hero Splendor engine and got a brand new engine fitted after that I rode about 1600 Kms but my bike is giving mileage of 45 Km/l max. My first service will be  due on 2000km. What should I do I heard that mileage increases after first service.

Comment: So you don't want an increased mileage?

Comment: Ya I am only asking about how to increase mileage